# x must be character or SQL when update mysql table from R

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, rodbc

I have mysql table `incoming_aviasales_prediction_model`. It contains 24 columns. I need update only two columns. I do so.

```
library(dbx)

> db <- dbxConnect(adapter="mysql", 
+                  dbname="rod_ml",
+                  host="1.2.3.4",
+                  pass="1234",user="bi",
+                  table="incoming_aviasales_prediction_model"
+                  )
> db
<MySQLConnection:0,6>
```

Here date.frame with these 2 columns.

```
> str(records)
'data.frame':  88320 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ aviasales_prediction_id: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ aviasales_prediction   : num  0.318 0.291 0.238 0.213 0.193 ...
```

comand to update

```
> dbxUpdate(db, table, records, where_cols=c("aviasales_prediction_id"))
```

after i get the error

```
 x must be character or SQL
```

What does it mean and how update my table?

```
traceback()
> traceback()
5: stop("x must be character or SQL", call. = FALSE)
4: DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn, cols)
3: DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn, cols)
2: quoteIdent(conn, table)
1: dbxUpdate(db, table, records, where_cols = c("aviasales_prediction_id"))
```

Comment: Did you define `table` to be a string indicating the target SQL table, or is it seeing the base function named `table` instead?

Comment: could you please insert the complete error message? Also the result of `traceback()` could be helpful

Comment: @mnist here traceback > traceback()
5: stop("x must be character or SQL", call. = FALSE)
4: DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn, cols)
3: DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn, cols)
2: quoteIdent(conn, table)
1: dbxUpdate(db, table, records, where_cols = c("aviasales_prediction_id"))